# 1 to at least 200 Latin list cardinal numbers

Tags: spelling, numbers

Aiming to answer this [Stack Exchange puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98238/multilanguage-generalization-of-what-number-is-that-asks-grandpa/98250#98250), I am looking for a list of the n first numbers with n being a positive integer greater than 200. I already have a list of the first 100 numbers by searching on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_numerals) then [this website](https://blogs.transparent.com/latin/latin-numbers-1-100/).

If your time required to find this list linearly depends on the length of the list or worst, you can stop at 1000. If this time is constant no matter the length of your list, do not hesitate to reach 10 000, or even 1 million.

Answer (score 7):

For numbers between 100 and 1000 you can just take the components out of the Wikipedia table you found.

> ascendit Simon Petrus et traxit rete in terram plenum magnis piscibus **centum quinquaginta tribus** (153 - note the declension) et cum tanti essent non est scissum rete

([John 21:11, Vulgata](https://www.biblestudytools.com/vul/john/21.html))

> et fratres eius principes patrum **ducenti quadraginta duo** (242) et Amassai filius Azrihel filius Aazi filius Mosollamoth filius Emmer

([Nehemia 11:13, Vulgata](https://www.biblestudytools.com/vul/nehemiah/11.html))

> hic sapientia est qui habet intellectum conputet numerum bestiae numerus enim hominis est et numerus eius est **sescenti sexaginta sex** (666)

([Revelation 13:18, Vulgata](https://www.biblestudytools.com/vul/revelation/13.html))

Based on this, I wrote the following [JavaScript snippet](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/6a9eece8c8c23587510676e37f6842be) which yields the [following list for 0 to 2048](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/d9e234a7e1fc9a462e7599003350bc4a) - for a longer list, just execute the snippet yourself. Feel free to fork it to make a version that produces numbers in equally valid formats (e.g. 'quattuor et vīgintī' for 24).

Comment: Haha! I find it so cool to see you already have an account on Latin.SE ;) Well that's is an excellent answer! I'll probably select it if no one yields a longer list. I didn't want to write the algorithm and was hoping some one already wrote it somewhere, well... You wrote it at last. Big +1

Comment: I hesitated posting here, or in StackOverflow. Do you think my final choice is the right one?

Comment: Thanks! This is a better place; it doesn't *require* programming, you can probably get very far with copy, paste, Find & Replace in a text editor.

Comment: Applying the subtractive rule to 98, 99 is questionable (one single attestation of *undecentum* in classical Latin, *duodecentum* apparently none at all). Applying it to 198, 199, 298, 299 etc. or even saying *undemille* for 999 is probably just wrong. See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Latin_cardinal_numerals#Counting_backwards) for details. In any event the additive forms are also legal (like *octo et viginti*), which might be interesting when looking for anagrams.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel thank you, I'll adjust the script. At least it's not as complicated as [Danish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_language#Numerals) ...

Answer (score 7):

Here is a nice list of Latin cardinal, ordinal, adverbial and distributive numerals going from 1 to 1,000,000 (continuously to 1,000, then with gaps):

https://www.arndt-bruenner.de/mathe/scripts/numeraliatab.htm

Ignore the German translations in the first three rows. Each rows starts with the number in Arabic, then in Roman digits, followed by the Latin numerals.  Note: Two-part numerals post 20 can also be written with *et*, for example: *viginti et unus* or *unus et viginti*.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think you can change your algorithm so it's continuous up to for instance 5,000? It's much more valuable **within the scope of my question** than having it with gaps up to 1,000 billion for instance :) +1 !

Comment: @JKHA I'm afraid I cannot do that, because it's not my list :)

Comment: @JKHA With a bit of manual labor you can extend the list easily: The word for 1463 is the concatenation of 1000 and 463, possibly with *et* in between. That should work quickly and easily enough for computer checks.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Oh cool! So any Latin number for any n in {10001...1999} is 1000 and the rest, with a space between?

Thank you Sebastian, that is a great answer ;)